# get_user_details error when some users were suspended

Tags: python, twitter

I am trying to look up user details for a given list of twitter users. However, some users on the given list have been suspended. Therefore, the programming process stopped when it encountered the first suspended username on the list. How can I skip those suspended usernames on the list and make the programming process continue to look up the rest of usernames?

My codes are listed below.

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    #authenticating the app (https://apps.twitter.com/)
    auth = tweepy.auth.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
    auth.set_access_token(oauth_token, oauth_token_secret)
    api = tweepy.API(auth)

      for username in df.username:
        print(username)
        xx = get_user_details(username)
        print(xx.location)
```

I expected to get the location info for all users, but the process stopped at User5. The error message said that the User5 account has been suspended. So, how can I skip this suspended user and continue to look up for the rest usernames?

```
User1
Orlando and everywhere else ✈️
User2
Omaha, NE
User3
Chicago, IL
User4
United States
User5
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TweepError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-11-574b6d4ee402> in <module>
      8     for username in df.username:
      9         print(username)
---> 10         xx = get_user_details(username)
     11         print(xx.location)
     12 

<ipython-input-8-216070e281ce> in get_user_details(username)
      1 def get_user_details(username):
----> 2         userobj = api.get_user(username)
      3         return userobj

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tweepy\binder.py in _call(*args, **kwargs)
    248                 return method
    249             else:
--> 250                 return method.execute()
    251         finally:
    252             method.session.close()

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tweepy\binder.py in execute(self)
    231                     raise RateLimitError(error_msg, resp)
    232                 else:
--> 233                     raise TweepError(error_msg, resp, api_code=api_error_code)
    234 
    235             # Parse the response payload

TweepError: [{'code': 63, 'message': 'User has been suspended.'}]
```

Answer (score 1):

IIUC you can wrap the call to `get_user_details` with a `try` `except` and catch the `TweepError` exception explicitly:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    #authenticating the app (https://apps.twitter.com/)
    auth = tweepy.auth.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
    auth.set_access_token(oauth_token, oauth_token_secret)
    api = tweepy.API(auth)

      for username in df.username:
        print(username)
        try:
          xx = get_user_details(username)
          print(xx.location)
        except tweepy.TweepError as e:
          print("exception")
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try a try ... except block

```
for username in df.username:
    try:
        print(username)
        xx = get_user_details(username)
        print(xx.location)
    except Exception as e:
        <do something else>
```